# How to get audio and video link from the pdf?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented odf reader application for iphone.Now i want to get list of audio url and video url from the pdf.I dont know how it possible.Please help me for this query.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise in what exactly your problem is? A good start to ask would be to explain what technology you are using. I guess you are using the "CGPDFDocument" API?

Answer (score 1):

All right then, with your `CGPDFDocumentRef` pointing to a valid PDF Document you could iterate over all available Pages of the Document using the `CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages` and the `CGPDFDocumentGetPage` functions. The result of the `CGPDFDocumentGetPage` function is a `CGPDFPageRef` reference. Within the `CGPDFPage` API and the `CGPDFDocument` API you'll find the `CGPDFPageGetDictionary` function which returns you a `CGPDFDictionaryRef` reference. It depends on how your PDF is build but in one of those Dictionarys are the informations stored you need. You can call `CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction` function on the Dictionary, passing a function pointer to callback with this signature:

```
void ApplierFunction (const char *key,  CGPDFObjectRef object, void *info);
```

The callback is called for every key/value pair of the specific dictionary. You should find what you are looking for within one of the `CGPDFObjectRef` references.

Also take a look at the Documentation of `CGPDFDocument`, `CGPDFPage` and `CGPDFDictionary`.