# How to read the content of a pdf file in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Are you able to fetch the content of pdf file . I am trying to do the same , i had spend a lot of time on it , i don't get any solution, can you give me some solution .

Thanks,
Dinesh Thakur

Comment: I removed your email address. That's not how SO works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF viewing/annotating library for iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161257/pdf-viewing-annotating-library-for-iphone)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93297/newbie-wants-to-create-a-pdf-reader-for-ipod-touch-whats-the-best-approach , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272132/how-to-use-the-iphones-built-in-pdf-viewer-to-display-a-document , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362393/reading-pdf-files-as-string-through-iphone-application

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Consider reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280487/how-to-get-audio-and-video-link-from-the-pdf/3280792#3280792), it will point to the right direction.